# How do you compute the XOR Remainder used in CRC?

Tags: xor, crc, polynomial-math

I'm trying to remember how the math is worked out to compute the remainder of an XOR algorithm in Cyclical Redundancy Checks to verify the remainder bits of a network message.

I shouldn't have tossed that text book.

This is easily done in code, but how is it worked out by hand?

I know it looks something like a standard division algorithm, but I can't remember where to go from there to get the remainder.

```
      ___________
1010 | 101101000
```

**Note:** I did google it, but wasn't able to find a place where they mapped the steps in figuring the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is long division by binary 11. There is an example on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_CRC).

Answer (score 6):

```
1010 | 101101000
       1010
       0001 this result is 1011 XOR 1010 = 0001
          1010
          1010
          0000  thus no remainder.
```

Thus 101101000 is perfect and no error has occurred in transmission/reception

Answer (score 2):

In my experience it's easier to convert it to a polynomial when calculating by hand, especially when there're a lot of zeroes.

```
1010 = 1*x^3 + 0*x^2 + 1*x^1 + 0*x^0 = x^3 + x = x3 + x
101101000 = x8 + x6 + x5 + x3

       -------------------
x3 + x ) x8 + x6 + x5 + x3
```

Then you *divide the **largest term*** in the dividend (`x^8`) with the ***first term*** in the divisor (`x^3`), resulting in `x^5`. You put that number on top and then ***multiply*** it with each term in the divisor. This yields the following for the first iteration:

```
        x5
       -------------------
x3 + x ) x8 + x6 + x5 + x3
         x8 + x6
```

Doing XOR for each term then yields the new dividend: `x5 + x3`:

```
        x5
       -------------------
x3 + x ) x8 + x6 + x5 + x3
         x8 + x6
       -------------------
         x5 + x3
```

Follow the same pattern until the dividend's largest term is smaller then the divisor's largest term. After the calculations are complete it will look like this:

```
        x5 + x2
       -------------------
x3 + x ) x8 + x6 + x5 + x3
         x8 + x6
       -------------------
         x5 + x3
         x5 + x3
       -------------------
         0
```

The reminder in this case is 0, which would indicate that most likely no errors has occurred during the transmission.

Note: I've shortened `x^y` as `xy` in the example above to reduce the clutter in the answer, since SO doesn't support math equation formatting.

Note2: Adding/subtracting a multiple of the divisor from the dividend will also give the reminder 0, since `(P(x) + a*C(x)) / C(x) = P(x)/C(x) + a*C(x)/C(x)` gives the same reminder as `P(x)/C(x)` since the reminder of `a*C(x)/C(x)` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we want to divide 101110000 to 1001.

```
101110000
1001
--------- XOR the 1011 and 1001
0010
```

Now we will **remove the zeros at the beginning of our XOR result** which is 0010 and **slide numbers from the top**.

```
101110000
1001
--------- 
  1010
```

Continue the XOR 1001 with the result.

```
101110000
1001
--------- 
  1010
  1001
---------
  0011
--------- Remove zeros at the beginning
    1100
    1001
---------
    0101
--------- Remove zeros at the beginning
     1010
     1001
---------
     0011
```

Answer is 0011.